# Request reply pattern

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Producer P1 produces a message M1 and sends it to Consumer C1 using Topic T1 using a CorrelationId ="123" . Also, the Producer P1 produces a message M2 and sends it to Consumer C2 using Topic T2 using a correlationId = "123"

Both the consumers (C1 & C2) reply back with the response to the same Reply Topic R1.

In this scenario, should we use the `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` or `AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

That scenario is not supported by the `AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate`; it is for sending the same message to multiple consumers and aggregating their replies.

For your use case you would need to use discrete `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` calls and perform the aggregation yourself.

If you use the same reply topic, you should probably set `sharedReplyTopic` to `true` to avoid log noise.

The reply containers will have to have different `group.id`s.

**EDIT**

Here's an example sending 2 requests asynchronously and correlating the replies; you don't need two templates because the destination topic is in the `ProducerRecord`...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So74684025Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So74684025Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rkt(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
        factory.setReplyTemplate(template);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer("so74684025-replies");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("so74684025-replies");
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so74684025-1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so74684025-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic reply() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so74684025-replies").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rTemplate, Sender sender) {

        return args -> {
            sender.sendTwo(Uuid.randomUuid().toString(), rTemplate);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Sender {

    private final Map<String, List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>> outstanding = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void sendTwo(String correlation,
            ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rTemplate) {

        this.outstanding.computeIfAbsent(correlation, key -> Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()));

        CompletableFuture<List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        try {
            RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> future1 =
                    rTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord("so74684025-1", "Test1", correlation),
                            Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            System.out.println(future1.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata());
            RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> future2 =
                    rTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord("so74684025-2", "Test2", correlation),
                            Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            System.out.println(future2.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata());
            future1.whenComplete(receive(future));
            future2.whenComplete(receive(future));

            List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> result = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(result.stream()
                    .map(rec -> rec.value())
                    .toList());
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            future.completeExceptionally(e);
            return;
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            future.completeExceptionally(e.getCause());
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
        finally {
            this.outstanding.remove(correlation);
        }
    }

    private ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord(String topic, String text, String correlation) {
        Headers headers = new RecordHeaders();
        headers.add("app.correlation", correlation.getBytes());
        return new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, 0, null, text, headers);
    }

    private BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, Throwable> receive(
            CompletableFuture<List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>> future) {

        return (record, exception) -> {
            if (exception != null) {
                future.completeExceptionally(exception);
            }
            else {
                // Needs error checking (missing header)
                String correlation = new String(record.headers().lastHeader("app.correlation").value());
                // So does this (missing correlation)
                List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records = this.outstanding.get(correlation);
                records.add(record);
                if (records.size() == 2) {
                    future.complete(records);
                }
            }
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {


    @KafkaListener(id = "so74684025-1", topics = "so74684025-1")
    @SendTo
    Message<String> listen1(Message<String> in) {
        System.out.println("1: " + in.getPayload());
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(in.getPayload().toUpperCase())
                .setHeader("app.correlation", in.getHeaders().get("app.correlation"))
                .build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so74684025-2", topics = "so74684025-2")
    @SendTo
    Message<String> listen2(Message<String> in) {
        System.out.println("2: " + in.getPayload());
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(in.getPayload() + in.getPayload())
                .setHeader("app.correlation", in.getHeaders().get("app.correlation"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

```
1: Test1
2: Test2
[Test2Test2, TEST1]
```

Comment: For your use case you would need to use discrete ReplyingKafkaTemplate calls and perform the aggregation yourself.

- Does this mean it has to be synchronous ReplyingKafkaTemplate calls ?

Comment: No; the template returns a future from which you can get asynchronous completion (`CompletableFuture` in 3.0+ and `ListenableFuture` in earlier versions).

Comment: Thanks Gary. So, this should work with the same co-relation id being used for separate request or should i use distinct co-relation id for both the request?

Also, the reply containers here means the Consumers C1 & C2 should have different group.ids , right?

Comment: You should use a different header for correlating the results; each template will need to correlate its own request/reply using its standard header. Yes; different groups for each template's replies.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Just edited my post to include separate methods with different correlation id. Will something like that work?

Comment: `sendAndReceive.get()` will block so if you call both on the same thread, they will be sequential; I can create an example if you like.

Comment: That would help, Gary

Comment: You don't need two templates; I added an example.

Comment: Thanks Gary, will try this out, i am assuming we would need to set the sharedReplyTopic = true in the Replyingkafkatemplate as well?

Comment: It won’t hurt, but not needed because there is only one template in my example.

Comment: A separate question: Suppose I have message M1 broadcasted to a Topic T1 and multiple consumers (C1,C2,C3,C4) are listening to it. These consumers filter the messages and only C2 and C4 acts on it and send back a reply to a shared reply topic. In this scenario, we would add a filter at the consumer level and after that can we use AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate?

Comment: Yes, the `AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate` accepts a `releaseStrategy` which is called when each reply is received (and after a timeout if `returnPartialOnTimeout` is true). The release strategy decides when/if the aggregation is complete. If it returns false after a timeout, the responses are discarded.

Comment: You should use a different header for correlating the results; each template will need to correlate its own request/reply using its standard header. Yes; different groups for each template's replies.  – Gary Russell 2 days ago

-This is not accurate anymore as in the example given above it looks like a single template is being used with one common co-relation Id. Can you please confirm?

Comment: No. Each request is using its own internal correlation header to correlate the request and reply. The custom header is then used to aggregate the two replies.